# Subprocess | Script to Script continuous input/output

Tags: python, subprocess

Been all over the internet in an attempt to find a solution.

### **My Goal:**

Two Scripts total.

First: sending user-input - and latching onto what Script 2 Prints out.

Second: receiving user-input, Printing it.

**Example:**

Script 1 sends 'Hi'

Script 2: Print("User-input received")

Script 1: catching Script 2 output (which in this case is: "User-input received")

**What's the catch?**

Script 2 is a terminal like script. it is suppose to run forever, just waiting for user input(in our case waiting for script 1 to feed it) 
Popening, sending, receving and closing is a not what I am aiming for.

So essentially Script 2 process is always open while Script 1 could be forced to open, send, catch output and close.

Minimal Example of the Code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
def runScript(file, fileName):
    proc = Popen([file], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell=False) 
    if fileName == "Script2.py"
        proc.stdin.write("Something")
        proc.stdin.flush()
    proc.stdout.readline()
```

### **Most of the problems I came across were:**

- Processes Freezing/Hanging.
- Subprocess makes Script 2 open receive, print and close.

*I've searched the whole internet, so far been using Subprocess Popen, specific Stdin and Stdout and not communication as it made my entire .Py hang. 
Been all over stack overflow, some suggested a module named Pexpect which is no longer supported. I am lost. Is there a module for what I am searching, can it be done with subprocess.*

Comment: please post your scripts here (or a reduced version to match a [mcve])

Comment: Code not on this computer, made this thread using this one. Added the most minimal version of what the code `somewhat` looks like. Script 2 is still opened and closed. and I am unable to keep the subprocess alive outside the def.

Comment: A [mcve] should be *complete* and *verifiable* -- it should be obvious to someone if it works or not, just copy-and-pasting code to run it themselves without needing to do extra setup ("extra setup" including creating a `__main__`, or writing to specific filenames, or so forth).

Comment: From your description it really sounds like Script 2 should be running on its own and not a subprocess.  You should look into interprocess communication (ipc) stuff and maybe use a unix socket or a shared pty.

Comment: I am looking for a script that runs another script and keeps it alive until the first scrips closes. And sends I/O